# How to reset a Random Number in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, random, numbers

I tried to make Guess the Number game that the number generate using this code:

```
var randomNumber: Int = Random().nextInt(50)
```

and not only that, I tried to put the retry button and reset function:

```
        fun initializeGame(){
        status.text = ""
        tGuess.text = ""
        randomNumber
        btnGuess.isEnabled = true
        guessCount = 0
        tCounter.text = "The Chances Remain: $guessCount / $guessLimit"
    }
```

The problem is I can't reset the random generator. Sorry for the bad explanation. I'm not very good at English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `randomNumber = Random().nextInt(50)` as your `randomNumber` is `var`.

Also, not to create `Random` object every time, you could store it in variable and reuse that instead, static variable preferably.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The random number is working but im trying to reset the random number to another number. For example, the first random number = 10, and after reset the number, random number = 45. Is is possible?

Comment: If in `initializeGame` function you put the line from the answer, `randomNumber` will get random integer each time `initializeGame` is called. If you want some specific values (not random), then you could put them in list and take them from here, but I think you want just randomness?

Comment: *static variable preferably* - there are no statics in Kotlin, what do you mean? Also, if you're not customizing the seed, you could use the `Random` companion object by removing the parentheses. This way you don't even need to store it yourself: `Random.nextInt(50)`

Comment: @Joffrey Yes, there aren't statics same as in Java, but I feel like `static` is a very general term, Kotlin's equivalent is indeed a companion object.